# JavaScript /regex/.test() give a function as parameter

Tags: javascript, regex

I check the Mollzia and MS document, I only find regex.test(str) API. However, I saw a usage of test(function(){}) in John Resig's Class.js which made me very confused.

source code: [class.js](http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/)

the code:

```
fnTest = /xyz/.test(function(){xyz;}) ? /\b_super\b/ : /.*/;
```

and

```
fnTest.test(prop[name])
```

what they do?

on firebug

```
console.log(/xyz/.test(function(){xyz;}))//true;
console.log(/xyz/.test(function(){}))//false;
console.log(/xyz/.test(function(){console(xyz);}))//true; console(xyz) not run
```

Comment: The function is never ran, it is stringified (implicitly) - that's the point of the test. Your last snippet should yield `true`, btw.

Comment: thanks I run the script again, last one this true. but I don't know why the first time is false.

Answer (score 0):

I think that

```
fnTest = /xyz/.test(function(){xyz;}) ? /\b_super\b/ : /.*/;
```

is a form of browser feature detection. He's passing a function object to the "test" method, which should convert the function object to a string. If the result of that actually does include the string "xyz", then the "fnTest" variable is initialized to the regex `/\b_super\b/`.  If not, which would be the case when a JavaScript environment wouldn't stringify a function like that for some reason (hint: IE), then "fnTest" is initialized to a regex that'll match anything.